# Access nested groups of a NetCDF file in Python

Tags: python, netcdf4

My NetCDF file has a nested structure, how do i access a nested group or variable?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

source_dataset = Dataset('/path/to/file.nc')
source_geo_group = source_dataset.groups['/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/']
```

This will throw the following error:

> "KeyError: '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/'"

My goal is to get the values of the variables in the nested group.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for getting nested groups is:

```
source_dataset = Dataset('/path/to/file.nc')
source_geo_group = source_dataset['/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/']
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

fn = '/path/to/file.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)

print('\n --> READ GROUPS')
print(ds.groups)

print('\n --> GET GROUP')
print(ds.groups['GROUP_NAME'])

print('\n --> READ GROUPS VARIABLES')
print(ds.groups['GROUP_NAME'].variables['VARIABLE_NAME'])

print('\n --> GET VARIABLE VALUE')
print(ds.groups['GROUP_NAME'].variables['VARIABLE_NAME'][:])
```